# How do I export kubernetes node/pod logs from a private network

Tags: kubernetes, logging, prometheus, monitoring, microk8s

I have an application running on microk8s at multiple edge server locations bounded by trusted VPN network. There are no inbound accesses allowed. No ssh nor rdp. We're only allowed rdp during the time of initial setup or during trimester maintenance windows. I'd want to scrape the logs from the kubernetes pods and send them through the network (outbound is allowed..!) and have them visualized on the grafana hosted somewhere on the cloud. Are there any out of the box solutioning that serves something like this. Azure and AWS has somekind of prometheus services that does the same inside a VPC, but what we are looking at here are private LAN networks.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with prometheus from my point of view is that it's a pull technology which depends on prometheus engine to pull requests from the exporters "pods in your case" so it's an inbound connection.

if elasticsearch is a possibility, you can easily setup your elasticsearch and kibana "visualization tool" outside your VPN network and then install logstash/fluentbit or even filebeat as a sidecar within your pods.
these sidecar's main job would be scraping your logs and send it to the elasticsearch nodes "push tech".

Comment: Even I was worried about the pull mechanism of prometheus and wondered if it'd solve the case. Let me also try with elasticsearch and kibana instead. Thanks btw!